# "Open in visual studio" link in an ASP.net exception default page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, browser, macros, add-in

When my ASP.NET application crashes (when it shows the default exception page), I'd like to be able to click on a line of the call stack in the browser and Visual Studio would open the code file at the given line.

Do you think it's possible ? Maybe with a macro/add-in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it link to the code file and set that code file extension mime type to use Visual Studio as a viewer.

Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have VisualStudio already attached to IIS and have it configured to break on thrown exceptions?